# Problem 8 from Herstein's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

This is a problem from Herstein's book. I have solved it when I was at subway :)

If $G$ is a finite group, show that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $a^N=e$ for all $a\in G$.

**Proof:** Let $|G|=n$ and take any $a\in G$. I am going to demonstrate that $\exists k=k(a)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^k=e$. Suppose it is false then $a\neq e, \ a^2\neq e, \ a^3\neq e, \dots $. Then $a^k\neq a^l$ (otherwise, some power of $a$ would be equal to $e$). Since $G$ is closed under operation then in thic case we get $|G|=\infty$ which is contradiction. Thus, for $\forall a\in G$ $\exists k=k(a)\in \mathbb{N}: \ a^k=e$. If $G=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ and we put $N:=\text{lcm}(k(a_1),\dots, k(a_n))$ we get our desired statement.

Please check out my solution.

Comment: Looks alright.!

Answer (score 1):

Your Answer and proof are correct.

Indeed, You can take a further step and prove that **$N\leq |G|=n$**.

**Hint:** Use contradiction again with the above result.

Comment: I don't think OP's proof suffices to show this. Keep in mind that the same $N$ has to work for all $a$'s, and that he only shows that $k(a) \leq \left|G\right|$, not that $k(a) \mid \left|G\right|$.